# C# memory issue

Tags: c#

My app is running out of memory every time I am running my application.

I went to app.config and enabled `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <runtime>
      <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled ="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Also I changed all doubles to float. Now I am wondering how one can change the entire project to a 64 bit process. I don't see the ability to do so when I create a new project. Is this possible? I am new to VS and C# so I am not 100% proficient in navigating. Any ideas?

I tested my process type via:

```
   if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        Console.WriteLine("64");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("32");
```

Comment: Untick the *Prefer 32-bit* checkbox and leave *AnyCPU*, or just set *x64* as platform. But before actually doing that, get a memory profiler and make sure everything looks correct. Getting out of memory shouldn't be a *normal* use case except if you're dealing with *lots* of data. Perhaps you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Does it happen in the same spot every time?  Sometimes that error doesnt mean what you think.  If you are new to C#/NET it could be a resource leak.

Comment: It should be much more important to figure out *why* your application is running out of memory than it is how to configure it to be 64-bit. There's two main reasons for your memory problems. 1) Your application is leaking memory, and 2) your application is using a lot of memory. Since you're not saying *anything* about your thoughts about why your application is running out of memory my bet is on nbr. 1, your application is leaking memory. As such, configuring it for 64-bit is just going to prolong its life somewhat, it's still going to crash with a memory problem sometime later.

Comment: I out but it's an recursive program that creates a lot of lists and strings. I will need to use the memory profiler to figure out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: So I ran a memory profiler and it looks like data tables in c# is chewing up a lot of my memory. Does that make sense? In my current case, more than 9000 data table are created at different points in time during the execution. And here I thought it was lists and strings...

Comment: Comparing to lists, or dictionaries, do data table take a lot more memory? Thhe profiler shows data.row is the main culprit....

Answer (score 2):

You can compile for both 32- and 64-bit architectures. This is how to change that value:

- Right-click your project in the Project view
- Select *Properties*
- Go to *Build*
- Under *Platform Target*, select **x64**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your application has probably different problem which you don't solve by changing it to 64 process or changing doubles to floats. Use memory profiler which is part of Visual Studio 2013 community edition.

I can't imagine that you have written such large object if you are new to C#.

Such memory problems can be caused by memory leaks or for example allocating too large bitmap (overflow in width or height) or anything else...